# How to dynamically pass in Model class name in Django view

Tags: django

"""Please, I have created some model classes in my django app.models. 
I want to access to objects of any of  the models in my views based on request.

My view looks like this:

```
def profile(request, course):
    Course_name = course
    Contents = model.objects.get()
    context = {obj: contents}
    return render(request, "pro.html", context)
```

"""My question is,  I want to replace model in model.objects.get() with the variable "course_name" 
But am getting this error,  'str' object has no attribute 'objects'
Please Help"""

Comment: Can you show your ,models.py

Answer (score -1):

Try using `eval(model).objects` instead of `model.objects`

The problem is that you are trying to read `objects` attribute from a string object which is not valid. you should first try to get the class which its name is equal to the value of `model` string and `eval` is the way to do that.

**Warning:**
The class which you want to access using `eval` should be visible in your code scope. So, import all possible models that you may need to use, and also put your code in a `try except` block

I hope this answers your question

Comment: Eval() did it and It  worked perfectly fine!!!  Thanks so much.... I ve got the problem solved!